# Call to undefined function blenc_encrypt()

Tags: encryption

I wanted encrypt my PHP source code using the `blenc_encrypt` function, but it is giving me error like this:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function blenc_encrypt()
```

I have tried to figure out in `php_ini` setting to uncomment extension like `blenc_encrypt` but there is no such setting available. What do I do to have `blenc_encrypt` available?

I am using php7.3

Comment: Thanks marteen for your valuable time. I will sure take care now onward.